# Detect if a column contains words from a separate list using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a table like this called df:

```
title             date            brand
big farm house    2022-01-01      A
ranch modern      2022-01-01      A
town house        2022-01-01      C
```

Then I have a table like this called match_list:

```
words_for_match
farm
town
clown
beach
city
pink
```

I'm looking to find a way to get a third column added using the mutate function that's true if the title contains any of the words from the match list.

I've tried this:

```
match_list <- match_list$words_for_match

match_list <- paste(company_names_list, collapse = "|")

df %>% 
   mutate(Flag = ifelse(str_detect(title, fixed(as.character(match_list))), "Yes", "No"))
```

But that didn't work and just ended up making everything "No". Any thoughts on how to teak it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer `fixed` as there is `|`.  We just need to remove the `fixed` and it should work.  In addition to prevent for substring matches, add the word boundary (`\\b`)

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
match_list <- sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", match_list)
df %>% 
   mutate(Flag = ifelse(str_detect(title, match_list), "Yes", "No"))
```

-output

```
            title       date brand Flag
1 big farm house 2022-01-01     A  Yes
2   ranch modern 2022-01-01     A   No
3     town house 2022-01-01     C  Yes
```

#### data

```
match_list <- structure(list(words_for_match = c("farm", "town", 
"clown", "beach", 
"city", "pink")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

df <- structure(list(title = c("big farm house", "ranch modern", "town house"
), date = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01"), brand = c("A", 
"A", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
# OP's code
match_list <- match_list$words_for_match
match_list <- paste(match_list, collapse = "|")
```

Comment: So this weirdly does work on the example data I provided, but I used this on my actual data and it now I have the opposite problem where it just provides a match for everything even if there isn't one